# "[nuxt] error caught during app initialization Error: Context conflict" on production

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've migrated my Nuxt 2 website to Nuxt 3 after dealing with all the headaches.
It's working completely fine locally but when I deploy it and use it live, something weird happens, websites working fine when I'm using it on my PC but as soon as I visit the website with my phone it stops working on all devices and thworing the following errors:

`[nuxt] error caught during app initialization Error: Context conflict`

`TypeError: can't access property "meta", r is undefined`

`TypeError: can't access property "isCE", _e is null`

website won't function till I regenerate and redeploy it again, it's quite weird.
**it's SPA with no SSR capabilities.**

Comment: Did you put `ssr: false` in your nuxt config?

Comment: @Marc yes I did